# Use orderby using linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have 4 column, facilities0id, name, date, Quantity. I have few problem here

How to use orderby based on the quantity. I wan to find top 3 row. Anyone can help, thanks

```
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

    var query = from p in db.Facilities
                join v in db.Reservations on p.facilities_id equals v.facilities_id
                join c in db.Reservation_Details on v.reservation_id equals    
                c.resevation_id
                where SqlMethods.Like(c.date, "%" + DropDownList1.Text + "%")
                select new
                {
                    p.facilities_id,
                    p.name,
                    c.date,
                    Quantity = p.Reservations.Count()

                };

    GridView1.DataSource = query.GroupBy(x => x.facilities_id)
                       .Select(g => g.First())
                       .ToList();

    GridView1.DataBind();

    int totalRowsCount = GridView1.Rows.Count;
    Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    Label3.Text = totalRowsCount.ToString() + " record(s)";
    Label4.Text = DropDownList1.Text;
```

Data in my database

```
 facilities_id      name       date      Quantity
   F001              cc     12-12-2014     3
   F002              vv     12-12-2014     2
   F003              gg     12-12-2014     1
   F004              bb     12-12-2014     5
```

Here is my expected output

```
  facilities_id     name       date     Quantity
   F004              bb     12-12-2014     5
   F001              cc     12-12-2014     3
   F002              vv     12-12-2014     2
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `OrderByDescending` to sort your records by `Quantity` in descending order,then `Take` first `3` records:

```
query.GroupBy(x => x.facilities_id)
     .Select(g => g.First())
     .OrderByDescending(x => x.Quantity)
     .Take(3)
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use For Descending "OrderByDescending"

`.OrderByDescending(x => x.Quantity);`

Use For Ascending "OrderBy"

`OrderBy(x => x.Quantity);`

Answer (score 0):

you need to first use order by descending for column quantity and then take first three rows